# Does new version of Cassandra (3.11.0) has support for nested JSON objects?

Tags: json, cassandra, nested

Is this type of nested JSON possible to store in Cassandra table and query any field from it?

```
{"data":[{"stuff":[
    {"onetype":[
        {"id":1,"name":"John Doe"},
        {"id":2,"name":"Don Joeh"}
    ]},
    {"othertype":[
        {"id":2,"company":"ACME"}
    ]}]
},{"otherstuff":[
    {"thing":
        [[1,42],[2,2]]
    }]
}]}
```

I read about [support for JSON](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertJSON.html) in Cassandra but that seems to be very simple 1 level JSON (not nested).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a support for JSON as JSON, it's just a representation of regular row using JSON format.

Cassandra doesn't have support for JSON, but you can use non-atomic data types (sets,maps etc) or user defined types (UDFs) to achieve several levels of nested objects.

Comment: Ok, so if I get nested JSON from customer - Cassandra does not support natively? (like Mongo or Elastic Search) I will need to build either UDF or use sets/maps etc..

Comment: Correct, you get it right. But if you need just to save it, you can save it as text and parse on application level.